# How many Virtual Private Clouds can be created in a gcp project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

We want to create one Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) per cluster per project. Do we have any limit on the number of VPC per project in GCP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the limits for users of a platform should be asked of the platform customer service.

Answer (score 0):

The default limit for number of networks (such as a VPC) per project is 15.

To [check your quota](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#checking-your-quota), run this command with your project ID:
`gcloud compute project-info describe --project [PROJECT_ID]`.

In the `quotas` field of the output, look for the entry with `metric: NETWORKS` and check the `limit` field.